# Use jq to retrieve fields specified on command line

Tags: jq

Given this input

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "f1": "one",
    "f2": "two",
    "f3": "three"
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to specify on the jq command line which fields to retrieve and spit *their* values out space-delimited on the same line.

`jq -r 'some-filter' --argjson fields '["f3","f1"]' test.json`

Result: `three one`

`jq -r 'some-filter' --argjson fields '["f2"]' test.json`

Result: `two`

I've tried several variations of this filter, with no luck

```
.attributes
 | $fields | . as $f | "\($f)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* do it using variable-symbolic binding (as you attempted) as

```
jq -r --argjson fields '["f3","f1"]' '[$fields[] as $f | .attributes | .[$f]] | join(" ")' test.json
```

or slightly more compactly

```
jq -r --argjson fields '["f3","f1"]' '[$fields[] as $f | .attributes[$f]] | join(" ")' test.json
```

but at least with jq 1.6 it seems you can just pass the `$fields[]` iterator to a *generic object index* of the form `.[<string>]`

```
jq -r --argjson fields '["f3","f1"]' '[.attributes[$fields[]]] | join(" ")' test.json
```

ex.

```
$ jq -r --argjson fields '["f3","f1"]' '[.attributes[$fields[]]] | join(" ")' test.json
three one
$ jq -r --argjson fields '["f2"]' '[.attributes[$fields[]]] | join(" ")' test.json
two
```

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to pass in a JSON array with the keys whose values you want to extract, you could do that like so

```bash
jq -r --argjson keys '["f3", "f1"]' '.attributes[$keys[]]' file.json
```

Given the data in the question, this would return

```
three
one
```

To get these on the same line with a space delimiter:

```bash
jq -r --argjson keys '["f3", "f1"]' '[.attributes[$keys[]]] | join(" ")' file.json
```

or, by simply passing the output of the first command to `paste -d ' ' -s -`:

```bash
jq -r --argjson keys '["f3", "f1"]' '.attributes[$keys[]]' file.json |
paste -d ' ' -s -
```

It would be more convenient for the user of the command to be able to mention the fields they want without having to create a JSON array (potentially having to remember to encode the keys properly):

```bash
jq -r '.attributes[$ARGS.positional[]]' file.json --args f3 f1
```

Or, for the space-delimited single-line output variant:

```bash
jq -r '.attributes[$ARGS.positional[]]' file.json --args f3 f1 |
paste -d ' ' -s -
```

Note that `--args` and the subsequent arguments need to be last on the command line.